# TR2 for homotopy category of stable $\infty$-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

I’m trying to understand Lurie’s proof that the homotopy category of a stable $\infty$-category is triangulated. In showing TR2, he constructs a diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> Y @>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0’ @>>> Z @>>> W \\
@. @VVV @VuVV \\
@. 0’’ @>>> V
\end{CD}$$
in which every square is a pushout in some stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal C$.
He then asserts a map between the suspensions
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVV \\
0’ @>>> W
\end{CD}$$
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>>> 0\\
@VVV @VVV \\
0’’ @>>> V
\end{CD}$$
giving rise to commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W @>>> X[1]\\
@VuVV @Vf[1]VV \\
V @>>> Y[1]
\end{CD}$$
in $h\mathcal C$. I think in fact what is needed for this commutative square is that the above map between suspensions specifically have components $f$ and $u$ between the initial vertices and terminal vertices, respectively.
By repeated application of HTT.4.3.2.15, the first (large) diagram is determined up to contractible choices by $f$, and, if $\mathcal C$ is stable, also determined up to contractible choices by $u$. Similarly, the map of suspensions is determined by the map $X\to Y$ or by the map $X[1]\simeq W\to V\simeq Y[1]$ (as $\Sigma$ is an equivalence). So the data of the large diagram is equivalent to the data of a map between the suspensions, and each is specified two different ways (via $f$/the map on initial vertices or $u$/the map on cocone points). I want to know why these are in correspondence. Another way of saying this is, the map $f$ determines, via the large diagram, a map $u$, which determines a map $X[1]\to Y[1]$ (always up to contractible choices), but why is this map homotopic to $f[1]$? This is equivalent to the assertion that the construction of the large diagram computes the suspension functor $\Sigma$ on edges of $\mathcal C$. One way to see this would be to construct a map between suspensions (a diagram $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\to\mathcal C$) directly from the data of the large diagram, but I don’t see how to fill in the most obvious candidate. (I could do so if I knew how to fill an outer horn $\Delta^3_0\hookrightarrow\mathcal C$ with the property that both interior vertices are zero objects, so every edge is a zero map.) Any tips would be a big help – thank you!

**Edit 5/20**
I can see the claim if it is true that given a cofiber sequence $X\to Y\to Z$ corresponding to a pushout
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> Z,
\end{CD}$$
then if I replace the bottom 2-simplex ($X\to 0\to Z$) of the diagram $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\to\mathcal C$ with any other one with the same vertices and long edge, the resulting diagram $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\to\mathcal C$ is still a pushout.

Comment: In short, the limit $\lim\colon\operatorname{Fun}(K,\mathcal C)\to\operatorname{Fun}(K^\triangleleft,\mathcal C)$ is functorial. Apply this to the pullback diagram.

Comment: I’m certainly aware of this fact (it underpins the statements in my last paragraph), but I don’t see how the claim follows from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This is equivalent to the assertion that the construction of the large diagram computes the suspension functor $\Sigma$"

My previous answer was based on me misreading this quote :)

You want to show that this large diagram *computes* $\Sigma$. Lurie says some words about why that is : he says that the large diagram induces a morphism from one square to the next, namely from the square

\begin{CD}X @>>> 0 \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> W\end{CD} to the square \begin{CD}Y @>>> 0 \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> V\end{CD}

Now the first square (the second too, but I need it for the first) is left Kan extended from its restriction to the span $0\leftarrow X \to 0$ (that is what it means to be a pushout), so a map between these two squares is entirely determined by a map between the corresponding spans.

But now the second span (the first one too, but I need it for the second) is right Kan extended from the single vertex $Y$, so a map between the spans is the same thing as a map between these vertices. In this case, by design, the map between the vertices is $f$.

What I'm saying is : the map between the squares that you get from the large diagram, which one $W\to V$ is precisely your $u$ , is the only map (up to a contractible space) of squares which restricts to $f : X\to Y$. But the map of squares which induces $\Sigma f : \Sigma X\to \Sigma Y$ also restricts to $f$, by definition.

So the two maps of squares must be the same, and in particular the two maps $u$ and $\Sigma f: \Sigma X\to \Sigma Y$ must be the same.

So this reduces to showing that the two squares

(\begin{CD}X @>>> 0 \\ 
@VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> W\end{CD} and the other one with $Y$)

are indeed pushout squares. But for both it follows from pasting of pushout squares.

EDIT : Regarding the comments. If you agree that the indexing category for the big diagram is a poset, then a map of squares in this diagram (i.e. a map $(\Delta^1)^3\to K$ where $K$ is the indexing category) is entirely determined by where it sends the vertices, together with the *property* that for each arrow in $(\Delta^1)^3$, the corresponding vertices in $K$ have an arrow between them.

So here, to get an arrow between the two squares in question from the big diagram, you need an arrow from $X$ to $Y$ (ok you have one, it's $f$), an arrow from $0$ to itself (ok, it's $id$), an arrow from $0'$ to $0''$ (ok, just go $0' \to Z\to 0''$), and finally an arrow from $W$ to $V$ (ok, it's $u$). Crucially, these arrows are in $K$, so you get a map $(\Delta^1)^3\to K$ (again, here I'm really using that $K$ is a poset) and thus, because your big diagram was originally something like $K\to \mathcal C$, you can precompose and get $(\Delta^1)^3\to \mathcal C$. Because of how you chose the vertices and arrows, this map of squares has, on the top left vertex $f$ and on the bottom right vertex $u$, therefore $u$ is identified with $\Sigma f$.

(note : I said that I used that $K$ was a poset, but in fact if $K$ were only a $1$-category, all hope would not have been lost, as we would simply have had to further *check* that some diagrams commute - in a poset, any diagram commutes so we can skip this step).

(another way to phrase this is that (nerves of) posets are $1$-coskeletal )

EDIT 2 : I was a bit quick when I said $K$ is a poset. I meant that the $\infty$-category presented by $K$ was a poset, i.e. that $K$ was categorically equivalent to a poset. You can see this by computing $\mathfrak C[K]$, which you can do by explicitly writing $K= (\Delta^1)^2\coprod_{\Delta^1}(\Delta^1)^2\coprod_{\Delta^1}(\Delta^1)^2$ (which you can easily simplify, up to categorical equivalence to $(\Delta^1\times \Delta^2)\coprod_{\Delta^{\{1\}}\times\Delta^{\{1,2\}}} (\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1)$, and then you have to do a bit of work)

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread compute for commute ...

Comment: In that case I feel like it must be by definition, but I will check later

Comment: @Tomo : I updated my answer with now a (hopefully) correct reading  :)

Comment: Dear Maxime, thank you for your updated answer. In some sense this answer is a restatement of my question. As you say, Lurie claims that the large diagram induces a morphism between the two suspension squares. I want to know precisely *how* the large diagram does this. I agree with you – both the large diagram and the map of squares are independently determined by the map f, or the map u. We know that both f and u determine the same large diagram. We want to conclude that they also determine the same map of squares. So we must understand how the large diagram induces a *unique* map of squares.

Comment: (Of course, as always ‘unique’ means ‘unique up to contractible choices.’) One way to do this is to fill in an explicit ∆^1x∆^2x∆^1 diagram, which I don’t know how to fill in. There may be other ways. Do you see how?

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's unique. What matters is that it induces a map of squares with $f$ in the upper left corner and $u$ in the lower right corner. Then the argument above shows that $u$ is $\Sigma f$.

Comment: As to how it induces *a* map of squares, note that the indexing big diagram is (the nerve of) a 1-category, so you can simply produce a map of squares in that sense. In fact, it's the nerve of a *poset* so you just to check that there is a map between the squares, *edgewise* ! That's now easily done

Comment: I agree: all that needs to be shown is that there exists a map of squares with $f$ in the initial vertex and $u$ in the final one, and this is all I’ve been asking for since the beginning. Can you please explain explicitly why such a map of squares exists? I don’t understand your most recent comment. Are you claiming that to get a diagram $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\to\mathcal C$, one need only have a map $\partial(\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\times\Delta^1)\to\mathcal C$? I don’t understand why that would be true.

Comment: No, that's not true for $\mathcal C$. But it's true for the indexing category of the big original diagram (let's call it $K$) because it's the nerve of a poset. But it also suffices to know it's the nerve of a $1$-category because then you just have to check *that* the side squares commute

Comment: I agree that the indexing categories of the large diagram and of the map of squares are (nerves of) posets.. I still do not understand how the large diagram induces a map of squares with components $f$ and $u$. If you know how, I’d be grateful if you’d update your answer with the construction. That construction is the only thing I’ve been asking for since the beginning, and I still don’t have it, so the question remains open. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add this. This is really about $K$ being a poset (or a $1$-category) so that you can easily construct $(\Delta^1)^3\to K$ with no homotopy coherence issues, and then compose with $K\to \mathcal C$

Comment: I’m sorry, K is not the nerve of a poset or a 1-category. I was mistaken when I agreed earlier. If K were the nerve of a 1-category, there would be an edge from X to W, and there would be nondegenerate 4-simplices in K, etc.

Comment: It is, up to categorical equivalence. I can add some words about that too

Comment: You write about the first square that it is left Kan extended and about the second that it is right Kan extended. Are not they both left Kan extended?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : it's not the square that is right Kan extended, but the span $0 \leftarrow Y \to 0$ : the square (you are right, both of them) is left Kan extended from the span, and the span is right Kan extended from the vertex

Comment: You mean both squares are bicartesian, right? And from the first you need cocartesianness and from the second cartesianness?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : no, this is not what I mean. This *is* true, but not what I'm using. The diagram $0\leftarrow Y \to 0$ is a bone fide diagram, and I'm saying that it's right Kan extended from the diagram $Y$ (along the inclusion of the vertex into the walking span).

Comment: A map of squares where the domain is left Kan extended from the span amounts to a map between the corresponding spans, and then if the codomain span is right Kan extended from its vertex, this amounts to a map between the corresponding vertices

Comment: Aha now I see, thanks!

Comment: Great, I can now see the claim. I added the details separately. Was it clear to you just looking at the diagram that it was Joyal equivalent to the nerve of the poset it represents? It wasn’t at all clear to me. Thanks for the nice argument!

Comment: I can't say that the specific horns you came up with were obvious, but with enough practice these things are "apparent". Another point is that if you think in terms of left Kan extension, the construction of the original big diagram could easily have been done with the poset $P$ to begin with

Answer (score 1):

I’d like to give some more details to complement Maxime’s answer.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
1 @>>> 2 @>>> 3 \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
4 @>>> 5 @>>> 6 \\
@. @VVV @VVV \\
@. 7 @>>> 8
\end{CD}$$
This diagram defines a poset $P$ as well as a simplicial set $K= (\Delta^1)^2\coprod_{\Delta^1} (\Delta^1)^2\coprod_{\Delta^1} (\Delta^1)^2$. I claim that the map $K\hookrightarrow N(P)$ is inner anodyne. This will imply Maxime’s claim that this map is a categorical equivalence. It resolves our problem, since then the map $\mathcal C^{N(P)}\to\mathcal C^K$ will be a trivial fibration, so choosing a section $s$, the map of posets $[1]\times[1]\times[1]\to P$ indicated in Maxime’s answer gives a functor $\mathcal C^{N(P)}\to\mathcal C^{\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\times\Delta^1}$ which we can precompose with $s$ to obtain a functor $\mathcal C^K\to\mathcal C^{N(P)}\to\mathcal C^{\Delta^1\times\Delta^1\times\Delta^1}$ which, when applied to the large diagram in the original question, will produce the desired map of squares.

Now to prove the claim. As Maxime suggests, the map $K\hookrightarrow (\Delta^1\times\Delta^2)\coprod_{\Delta^{\{1\}}\times\Delta^{\{1,2\}}}(\Delta^1)^2$ is inner anodyne. Next, there is an inner anodyne map $(\Delta^1\times\Delta^2)\coprod_{\Delta^{\{1\}}\times\Delta^{\{1,2\}}}(\Delta^1)^2\hookrightarrow  (\Delta^1\times\Delta^2)\coprod_{(\Delta^1)^2}(\Delta^1\times\Delta^2)$,
where the copy of $(\Delta^1)^2$ appears as $\Delta^1\times\Delta^{\{1,2\}}$ of the first copy of $\Delta^1\times\Delta^2$ and as $\Delta^1\times\Delta^{\{0,1\}}$ of the second. (Note, this numbering is with respect to the usual numbering of simplices, and doesn’t refer to the numbers in the diagram above.) Now we can fill the following succession of inner horns, which will fill in all five nondegenerate 4-simplices of $N(P)$, hence all of $N(P)$. The inner horns are indexed by their spines.

1. 4 6 8 ($\Lambda_1^2$)
2. 4 5 6 8 ($\Lambda_2^3$)
3. 4 5 7 ($\Lambda_1^2$)
4. 4 5 7 8 ($\Lambda_1^3$)
5. 1 5 7 ($\Lambda_1^2$)
6. 1 4 5 7 ($\Lambda_2^3$)
7. 1 2 5 7 ($\Lambda_2^3$)
8. 1 4 8 ($\Lambda_1^2$)
9. 1 4 5 8 ($\Lambda_1^3$)
10. 1 5 7 8 ($\Lambda_1^3$)
11. 1 4 5 7 8 ($\Lambda_2^4$)
12. 1 2 5 8 ($\Lambda_2^3$)
13. 1 2 5 7 8 ($\Lambda_2^4$)
14. 1 5 6 8 ($\Lambda_1^3$)
15. 1 4 5 6 8 ($\Lambda_2^4$)
16. 1 2 5 6 8 ($\Lambda_2^4$)
17. 1 2 3 8 ($\Lambda_1^3$)
18. 1 2 3 6 8 ($\Lambda_1^4$)